# how can I make my code print my function if im working with csv files?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have to do a dict of list of dict but i think my data charging function is not working, I tried this method but its not returning nor printing anything[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cm6JZ.png)

I am working with a csv file and i have to upload the information from this file with a function but im not sure if it is ok. I am reading the file and giving each data a list with each information, then I tried to add each list to the dict I have to return but I tried to print the function and the dict i have to get as return but it did not work

Comment: You never read anything other than the first line.  `linea` never changes.  Change your `while` to `for linea in archivo:`.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with Tim Robert's comment. You're reading one line, then your while loop repeatedly operates on that line. Move your readline into your while loop (and initialize your var appropriately so it will run the first time and not bail).

You'll get more eyes on things here as well if you post code and not screenshots.